# How to count different words from a text on C?

Tags: c

I wrote this code but it looks so bad. This function prints how many times is repeated each word. Is there another way to do the same function simple and easy to understand?

```
int diffrentwords(FILE *myinput){
    int i,j,words[40],difwords=0;
char text[40][40];
char a;

rewind(myinput);
for(i=0;i<40;i++){
    words[i]=0;
    for(j=0;j<40;j++)
        text[i][j]=' ';
}
    for (i=0;i<40;i++){
    if(feof(myinput))
        break;
    for(j=0;j<40;j++){
        a=fgetc(myinput);
        if(a!=' ')
            text[i][j]=a;
        else{
            text[i][j]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
text[i][0]='\0';
i=0;

for(i=0;text[i][0]!='\0';i++)
    for(j=i+1;text[j][0]!='\0';j++)
        if(text[j][0]!=' ' && !(strcmp(text[i],text[j]))){
            words[i]++;
            text[j][0]=' ';
        }
for(i=0;text[i][0]!='\0';i++)
    if(text[i][0]!=' '){
        printf("%s \t %d\n",text[i],words[i]+1);
        difwords++;
    }
printf("\n");
return difwords;
```

}

Comment: Comments help make code easier to understand.

Comment: Are the words in the file on one line?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes i think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 is to read all of the words from the file.  `fscanf` can be used for this purpose. The nice thing about `fscanf` is that it will read entire words, handle all of the white space issues, and detect the end-of-file.  So the code to read the file looks like this

```
int count;
char word[40][40];
FILE *fp;

if ( (fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" )) == NULL )
    exit( 1 );

for ( count = 0; count < 40; count++ )
{
    if ( fscanf( fp, "%39s", word[count] ) != 1 )
        break;
}

fclose( fp );
```

Step 2 is to figure out how many unique words there are in the file. A word is counted as unique if none of the words before it in the array are the same.  For example, a word at index 9 is counted as unique if it doesn't match any of the words at index 0 through 8.

```
int i, j, unique, repeated;

unique = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    repeated = 0;
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        if ( strcmp( word[i], word[j] ) == 0 )
        {
            repeated = 1;
            break;
        }

    if ( !repeated )
    {
        unique++;
        printf( "%s\n", word[i] );
    }
}

printf( "The number of unique words is %d\n", unique );
```

Comment: @user3599630 If you think this question/answer will help future students/beginners you can vote up!

Answer (score 0):

First you should have the function for one and only one purpose.

You cannot have a function that read from the file and do count. ( single responsibilty)

Second, lets rethink again... you will have some function that return a line by line from the file.

Then you will have another function that read from the first one and try find space chars so it can consider a word.

Another function will take each word and search in some `array of struct {char* word; int count;}` and if it found the word, it increment the count, otherwise it sets it to 1.

By this you will have more organized and readable code.